# Android Adding to ListView notifyDataSetChanged() works only once?

Tags: android, listview

I am adding to a `listview` dynamically:

```
public class AddReferenceActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private List<BookingDetails> arrayOfBookings;
    private Activity mActivity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_reference);

        // Construct the data source
        arrayOfBookings = new ArrayList<BookingDetails>();
        // Create the adapter to convert the array to views
        adapter = new BookingRefAdapter(this, 0, arrayOfBookings);
        // Attach the adapter to a ListView
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvBookingRefs);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        btnBooking.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showProgress();
                //Validate Booking number
                String booking_ref = edtBooking.getText().toString();
                if (Constants.validateNotEmpty(booking_ref)){
                    //Associate
                    ApiManager.getService().associate(user_id, booking_ref, "", new Callback<BookingDetails>() {
                        @Override
                        public void success(BookingDetails booking, Response response) {
                            arrayOfBookings.add(booking);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Error Creating Booking Associations");
                        }
                    });
                }
                else{
                    Constants.showError(mActivity, "Booking Reference", "Booking Reference Can't be null");
                }
            }
        });
```

Problem is that only the first item is added to the list, the next time I add nothing is added.

Update `BookingRefAdapter.java`:

```
public class BookingRefAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BookingDetails>{
    public BookingRefAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<BookingDetails> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        BookingDetails book = getItem(position);
        //Check if existing view is being used, otherwise inflate the view
        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_booking_ref, parent, false);
        }

        TextView tvType = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvType);
        TextView tvNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvNumber);

        if (book.getBookingRef() != null){
            tvType.setText("Booking Reference");
            tvNumber.setText(book.getBookingRef());
        }
        else{
            tvType.setText("e-Ticket Number");
            tvNumber.setText(book.getEticket());
        }

       return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: @quicklearner Full code added...

Comment: You should post the `BookingRefAdapter` code

Comment: @Joseph82 Added, is that enough? It is a standard array Adapter. Can you provide a solution now or maybe I should upload the whole project to github?

Comment: Use the adapters add method.

Comment: @StevieG your solution should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comment, the problem can be related to your `ArrayAdapter` implementation. However, I can give you some suggest:

1) Make sure your `ListView` is not inside a `Scrollview`, as android won't know what to scroll. As specified on page 47 or [Google IO 10](https://dl.google.com/googleio/2010/android-world-of-listview-android.pdf)

2) If you don't need to initialize your `ListView` with any item (looking at your code, this seems thecase), you should not pass an empty List, (IMHO you could always avoid it) and you should use a constructor like this:

```
private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BookingDetails>{
    private Context mContext;
    public MyAdapter(Context c){
        super(c, 0);
        mContext = c;
    }
}
```

Avoid passing explicitally a list, you should not have problem with List reference, since the `ListView` is passed by reference, both Adapter and your external class (the `Activity`) can modify it.

3) Use the mehtod exposed by the Adapter for changing (adding, removing, etc) item inside ListView:

- add(Object o)
- addAll(Collection)
- remove(T object)

and so on. So, in your case, simple add item with this code line:

```
adapter.add(booking);
```

4) do not use `notifyDataSetChanged()` if it is not required. If you look at the source code of [add() method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.0_r1/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#ArrayAdapter.add%28java.lang.Object%29) you can see the code line:

```
if (mNotifyOnChange) notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Also the boolean mNotifyOnChange is initialized as true:

```
private boolean mNotifyOnChange = true;
```

So, notifyDataSetChanged() is automatically called when you add a item in your adapter.

Comment: First one adds, subsequent ones don't

Comment: Have you tried with these tips? Have you also checked if your `ArrayList` contains all the items you are adding?

Comment: Yes implemented all of them

Comment: In debug, your list  contains all the items you added?

Comment: I can't debug it because the `List` is not used I am only adding items with `adapter.add(i)`

Comment: You can always retrieve the number of items inside the adapter with `adapter.getCount()`. If the number of items is right, try to call (just after the adapter creation) `adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78298/discussion-between-joseph82-and-stevie-g).